# Load file from same folder as Python 3.x script inside package

Tags: python, file, loading, python-packaging, pkg-resources

Opening and loading data from a file that is situated in the same folder as the currently executing Python 3.x script can be done like this:

```
import os

mydata_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "mydata.txt")
with open(mydata_path, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
```

However once the script and `mydata.txt` files become part of a Python package this is not as straight forward anymore. I have managed to do this using a concoction of functions from the `pkg_resources` module such as `resource_exists()`, `resource_listdir()`, `resource_isdir()` and `resource_string()`. I won't put my code here because it is horrible and broken (but it sort of works).

Anyhow my question is; is there no way to manage the loading of a file in the same folder as the currently executing Python script that works regardles of wether the files are in a package or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`importlib.resources.read_text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.resources.read_text) in order to read a file that's located relative to a package:

```py
from importlib.resources import read_text

data = read_text('mypkg.foo', 'mydata.txt')
```

Comment: At least that is something. Thanks!